# Trying to access array offset on value of type null when using mysqli_fetch_array() in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, validation

In my login page. when username or password is incorrect then it is displays both if condition statements and also display this error: "Trying to access array offset on value of type null".kindly help me out to figure this out. thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

```
        if(isset($_POST['login']))
    {
        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];
        $sql="select * from users where user_name='".$username."' and password='".$password."' ";
        $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql); 
        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) === 1) 
        {
            echo '<script>alert("Login successfully")</script>';
        }
        else
        {   
            if($row["user_name"] != $_POST['username'])
            {   
                echo "username is incorrect";
            }
             if($row["password"] != $_POST['password'])
            {
                echo "password is incorrect"; 
            }
        }
    }
```

and here is the error:

> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\selfstudy\login.php on line 75

> username is incorrect

> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\selfstudy\login.php on line 79

> password is incorrect

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). Even [if you are escaping inputs, it's not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187) You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API instead of concatenating user-provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: ok. i will keep it in mind. thanks for the link

Comment: Because when  username or password is incorrect then $row is empty and you are trying to access offset of that empty $row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is likely to be thrown when no rows are returned from the DB, since the code only handles the condition where number of rows returned is equal to 1.

When 0 rows are returned, `$row` is `null`.
And when you are try to access array offsets `$row["user_name"]` and `$row["password"]`, it throws the error **Trying to access array offset on value of type null** since `$row["user_name"]` and `$row["password"]` don't exist.

To fix this, you must either handle the case where `mysqli_num_rows($result) === 0`, or you must check `isset($row["user_name"])` and `isset($row["password"])` beforehand.

**Note 1**: Depending on your table design, the code will fail if more than 1 row is returned. I suggest appending your SQL query with `LIMIT 1` to avoid this.

**Note 2**: It also seems like you're saving the passwords in the DB as plaintext. This is bad practice. Please look up password hashing. [This article](https://medium.com/codex/how-to-save-and-verify-password-using-php-and-mysql-64687086cc8d) is a good starting point.

**Note 3**: You may want to consider implementing a generic error message in your `else` block instead. Returning something like "**Your username/password is incorrect**"

**Note 4**: You are open to [SQL injection attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Please take a look at the answers in the provided link and implement parameterized prepared statements.

Comment: limit is useless, better make username unique. mysqli_num_rows is useless as well, you already have $row.